# Get file's URI for groovy script

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have a script that is dependent with another script. 
I'm kinda confused how to use the `@SourceURI` annotation so that the path of the first script will not be dependent on the second script's current location.

I used this but there's an error on the `sourceUri.resolve` part. I think I got it all wrong. It will error a NullPointerException

```
@SourceURI def sourceUri

String RELATIVE_LOCATION = "src/folder/NameOfFirstScript.groovy"
File MESSAGE_SENDER_FILE = new File(sourceUri.resolve(RELATIVE_LOCATION))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`@SourceURI @Field URI sourceUri` instead of `String`